# Erro ao gerar relatório de imagens

Tags: codeigniter, imagem, fopen

Tenho um código que tem várias fotos separadas por relatórios. Cada relatório pode qualquer quantidade de fotos. Ao clicar no botão para gerar esse relatório, se tem varias fotos (em torno de 60) ela começa a gerar erros ao invés de gera-lo. Não sei ao certo o motivo, mas quando o relatório é pequeno esses erros desaparecem.

A mensagem que aparecer é a seguir:

> Message:
>   fopen(http://site.com/imagens/caminho_da_foto/nome_da_foto.txt):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Meu código está em Codeigniter, e todas as fotos estão salvas no meu banco de dados, junto com seus relatórios.

A linha que aparecer o erro é a seguir:

```
$f->caminho_img = $l->caminho_img [0];
$ponteiro = fopen("http://site.com/imagens/" . $f->caminho_img . ".txt", true);
```

Comment: Você está carregando essas fotos em uma espécie de loop? (comando de repetição). Tem certeza de que os arquivos que você está requisitando realmente existem? Pela mensagem de erro, está dizendo que a requisição falhou pois não encontrou o destino.

Comment: @ThiagoYoithi conferi os arquivos, e todos existem com o mesmo caminho e nome que está sendo chamado.  As fotos estão carregadas dentro de um loop.